# Can we resize or decorate text in UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, xcode5

[image]

Basically I want texts to be smaller (or autoshrink).

I want some part of the texts to have a different color. I like near to be blue with different diminutive font.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to use a `UISearchBar`? I had a similar problem and solved it by using a UITextField instead. You can customize the `UITextField` to look equal to the `UISeachBar`.

The advantage of `UITextField`: You can use attributed text! That is a feature available since iOS 6.0 which you even can modify in the text fields attribute inspector. To set the attributed text programmatically use the textField.attributedText property. 
You can change the text as you like! Take a look at [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAttributedString). With that you can modify your string as described above.

Answer (score 2):

I guess **No**, You cant directly decorate text in UISearchBar.

But UISearchBar has a UITextField inside, but there's no property to access it. So, there is no way for doing it in a standard way.But there is a non-stardard way to workaround it. UISearchBar inherits from UIView, you can access it's subviews using [searchBar subviews]. If you print in the console it's subviews you will see that it have these views.

```
 UITextField *textField = [[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
```

`for ios7` [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7/19048870#19048870) for geting textfiled.

After it using [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can set color or font to textfiled.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples check them out.

[OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)