# Unable to change text color in a search bar for iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uisearchbar, textcolor

I need to change the text color in an `UISearchBar` text field. I tried the two answers in this post:

[UISearchBar text color change in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7)

But the text remains in its default gray color. I set that code in the `viewDidLoad` method. What can I be missing? Did somebody have this same problem?

Thanks

Comment: The default gray text of a search bar is not the text of the text field, it is the placeholder of the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I also set `[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];` and it worked... is it possible to also change the color of the small search icon in the text field?

Comment: You have to set your own image. See the `UISearchBar` docs.

Comment: If the question is answered, please add the answer in the form of an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

//This is done in Xcode 5.0 and its working btw i don't know whether it works with previous versions of Xcode or not....
// Also I wrote this method in viewDidLoad
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get the instance of the UITextField of the search bar
UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];

// Change search bar text color
searchField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: Accessing private instance variables this way is outside the scope of the public API and thus should not be used. Apple does not allow accessing private iVARS this way and this may as well get your app rejected from app store.