# How do you customise UISearchBar colors in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

I have searched quite a bit but cannot find a good answer to this.

I want to change the backgroundColor of the inner rounded view.

Like in Tweetbot on the search tap where it changes from gray to blue.

I understand that I probably need to iterate over the subviews but I don't know how to get the right object. (for the backgroundColor it's not the _searchLabel)

The default contrast of this element is so bad it's not even funny :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios?rq=1

Does this help?

Comment: nope :( I don't want to add a background image. just change the color of the inner rounded view.

Comment: I meant the solution 2 answers below that one your referring too

Comment: what answer exactly? they all change just the background image ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works. But note that you can't set a UIBarStyle beforehand or it will override everything.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19836215/1252720

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a better answer, I just stumbled across this thread and found a great solution: [UISearchBar text color change in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7)

If you look at the answer given by Sandeep-Systematix (not the accepted answer, but the answer right below), he mentions a really clean way to modify subviews in any class with this method:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

You can read more about this in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

**That said, here's what you'll need to change the white, rounded background of the UITextField inside the UISearchBar:**

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Now if you needed to create different UISearchBars with different styles, you would simply create a subclass of UISearchBar and you'd end up with something like this:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyCustomSearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code.

```
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
_searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
_searchBar.delegate         = self;
[self.view addSubView:_searchBar];

UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: This would lead to app store rejection.