# Change text color and border color of a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have an `UISearchBar`, with search style "minimal", and I want to change the text color and to have a white border with `1px width`. I'm trying with `tintcolor` but I don't get nothing

Thank you.

Comment: You can try with this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the text color of the `UISearchBar`, use this snippet

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
```

For the white border, try this out

```
for (id object in [[[yourSearchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;

        textFieldObject.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        textFieldObject.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        textFieldObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

*Edit*

You can add the first line for the search bar color anywhere in your app. Also, I have added one line for the `textColor` in the loop, check that out.

Comment: the second one worked, but the first one didn't. Where should I have to put it?

Comment: check out the edited answer. Just add `textFieldObject.textColor = [UIColor redColor];` in the code.

Comment: perfect, that worked. It also failed because I was using placeholder. Thank you :P

Comment: Haha... happens to the best of us!