# UISearch bar text color issue

Tags: xcode, uisearchbar

I have changed the search bar placeholder color to blue and text color to white. Normal conditions works fine.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
 [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:131/255.0 green:169/255.0 blue:202/255.0 alpha:1.0] ];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:42/255.0 green:93/255.0 blue:134/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

**Issue**
When I set Text

```
 self.searchbar.text = @"Some text";
```

The text displayed in search bar takes the placeholder color i.e blue but i want it to take white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "`UILabel`" for your text color, use "`UITextField`":

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:131/255.0 green:169/255.0 blue:202/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

And more information can be found in the answers of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7).