# Change UISearchBar textColor not working

Tags: google-maps, uisearchbar, google-places-api, uiappearance

I am using google places API for autoComplete widget. I am showing the full screen control in ios 9+ using swift. I am adding a full control as given in the docs.

I have added the code as shown in the docs. Now I want to change the searchBar text color to whiteColor.

So I tried this

```
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

But I am not getting the desired behaviour. Below is the screenshot

[image: **enter image description here**]

This has been given in Docs

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#use_a_table_data_source

But this is not working. I need help with regarding to this.

Comment: explain the desired output and the error you are getting

Comment: Its always better to elaborate question a bit and attach snapshot if possible otherwise difficult to get exact solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create an extension like follwoing:

```
public extension UISearchBar {

    public func setNewcolor(color: UIColor) {
        let clrChange = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        guard let sc = (clrChange.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else { return }
        sc.textColor = color
    }
}
```

And change color using following code:

```
 controller.searchBar.setNewcolor(UIColor.redColor())
```

Output is :

[image]

**Update:**

For the change color of searchBar text for the `GMSAutocompleteViewController` you need to do following code:

```
let searchBarTextAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())]
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
```

That change the text out put like following image:

[image]

And if you wish to change placeholder text and it's color for `searchBar`. You need to do following code:

```
let placeholderAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())]

let attributedPlaceholder: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Find a place", attributes: placeholderAttributes)
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

It will be show like:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use Bellow code for **Swift 3**

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]
  } else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For swift 4 ios 12

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes
            .updateValue(UIColor.white, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**UIAppearance protocol**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/) to get the appearance proxy for a class which is available in iOS 5.0 and later.

There are actually two ways to customize appearance for objects and to get the appearance proxy for the class.

- To customize the appearance of all instances of a class, use `appearance`.
- To customize the appearances for instances of a class when contained within an instance of a container class, or instances in a hierarchy, use `appearanceWhenContainedIn`.

You can apply this sample code:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
```

You can also try another option given in this SO post - [UISearchBar text color change in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048766/uisearchbar-text-color-change-in-ios-7).

I hope that covers your issue. Happy coding!

Comment: It doesnt cover my issue. I am using swift and in swift we cannot use defaulttext attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5:

```
let searchBarTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : AnyObject] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]

UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very easy, just access the textField inside that searchBar as so:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lastest on swift 5**

```swift
searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
```